# How to solve these two first order non-linear coupled differential equations that represents the velocity field of a vortex?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

[image] What is the solution of these coupled differential equations ?

$\frac{dx}{dt}=-sin(2\pi(y-\alpha))sin^2(\pi (x-\beta)) $       eqn 1

$\frac{dy}{dt}=  \;\; sin(2\pi(x-\beta))sin^2(\pi (y-\alpha))$  eqn 2

$\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants. These are the equations of a vortex velocity field. Figure shows the result that I got when I tried to numerically  follow the path for intial cordinates (x,y) = (6.5,6.25) and $(\alpha,\beta) = (5.76,6.01)$ with $dt = 1/12$ for 30 million iterations. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-2 \sin(\pi(y-\alpha))\cos(\pi(y-\alpha)) \sin^2(\pi (x-\beta))\tag 1$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=  2\sin(\pi(x-\beta))\cos(\pi(x-\beta))\sin^2(\pi (y-\alpha)) \tag 2$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\cos(\pi(x-\beta))\sin(\pi (y-\alpha)) }{\cos(\pi(y-\alpha)) \sin(\pi (x-\beta))} \tag 3$$
The ODE $(3)$ is separable.
$$\frac{\cos(\pi (y-\alpha)) }{ \sin(\pi(y-\alpha)) }dy=-\frac{\cos(\pi(x-\beta)) }{\sin(\pi (x-\beta))}dx$$
$$\ln|\sin(\pi(y-\alpha))| = -\ln|\sin(\pi(x-\beta))|+\text{constant}$$
General equation of the trajectories :
$$\boxed{\sin(\pi(y-\alpha))\sin(\pi(x-\beta))=C}\tag 4$$
Each trajectory depends on $C$ which is defined from the initial point $(x_0\;,\;y_0)$

$$C=\sin(\pi(y_0-\alpha))\sin(\pi(x_0-\beta)) \tag 5$$

One put $\sin(\pi(y-\alpha))=\frac{C}{\sin(\pi(x-\beta))}$ from $(4)$ into $(1)$ in order to eliminate $y$. 
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-2 \frac{C}{\sin(\pi(x-\beta))} \sqrt{1-\frac{C^2}{\sin^2(\pi(x-\beta))}} \sin^2(\pi (x-\beta))$$
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-2C \sqrt{\sin^2(\pi(x-\beta))-C^2}$$
$$t=-\frac{1}{2C}\int_{x_0}^x \frac{d\chi}{\sqrt{\sin^2(\pi(\chi-\beta))-C^2}}$$
$$t=-\frac{1}{2C}\int_{x_0}^x \frac{d\chi}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{4}-\pi(\chi-\beta))-C^2}}$$
$$t=-\frac{1}{2C\sqrt{1-C^2}}\int_{x_0}^x \frac{d\chi}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{1-C^2}\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{4}-\pi(\chi-\beta))}} \tag 6$$
$$t=-\frac{1}{2\pi C\sqrt{1-C^2}}\int_{\pi(x_0-\frac{1}{4}+\beta)}^{\pi(x-\frac{1}{4}+\beta)} \frac{d\xi}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{1-C^2}\sin^2(\xi)}}$$

$$t(x) = -\frac{1}{2\pi C\sqrt{1-C^2}}\left( \text{F}\left(\pi(x-\frac{1}{4}+\beta)\:,\:\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-C^2}}}\right) -\text{F}\left(\pi(x_0-\frac{1}{4}+\beta)\:,\:\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-C^2}}}\right)\right)$$
$\text{F}$ denotes the Elliptic Integral of the first kind : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html

For the inverse function $x(t)$ one can numerically integrate $(6)$ from $x_0$ up to the value of $x$ such as the value of $t$ be reached.

Proceed similarly from equations $(2)$ and $(4)$.

COMMENT :

The above result, analytical solution $(4)$ , is in contradiction with the numerical result from the OP computation. The analytical result is a periodic function which graphical representation is a closed curve.

My own numerical solving doesn't agree with the OP. On the figure below the curve from equation $(4)$ is drawn in red. The numerical calculus gives the curve drawn in black. They are undistinguishable one from the other. This confirmes that my analytical and numerical calculus are consistent.

[image]

I think that the increment of $t$ which was chosen $=1/12$ by the OP is much too large. The small numerical errors accumulate and cause the deviation from a closed curve to something like a spiral. I think that the increment of $t$ must be much smaller, for example $0.00001$ or less.

The above curve seems close to a circle because the chosen initial point $(x_0,y_0)$ is close to $(\alpha,\beta)$.

Another example below shows the result with initial point less close to $(\alpha,\beta)$ :

[image]

Comment: I had already went through the same path and but ended up in elliptic integral of first kind of x and I could not move forward to solve explicitly for x(t) or y(t). as shown  in newly added figure. I used the $ln|sin(\pi(y-\alpha))|= -ln|sin(\pi(x-\beta))|+ constant$ for substitution. If I would have used as you said (4), It wouldhave been $\int \frac{\sqrt(x^2-C^2)}{x^2sin^2x} dx$. Which seems more difficult to integrate.

Comment: Are you not surprized that the analytical result is in contradiction with your numerical result ? I added a comment at the end of my answer as a starting point to think about this.

Comment: You are correct. But I am not surpised of this as I was aware of it. Howeever small the dt is, given enough iterations, due to tangent pointing outside, it will end up in enlarging spiral, but it would give the feel of the solution and that was my intention behind the simulation. I didn't intend to confuse.

Being said that  proceeding analytically all I need is inverse of elliptic integral function. Is there one? even close approximation may be helpful, because I need a direct way to estimate x(t) and y(t). My searches were unsuccesfull in this path and I am not from math bg

Comment: I could find, it has something to do with Jacobi amplitude, but I am stuck.

Comment: I don't agree. It will not end up in enlarging spiral because there is no spiral. The solution of equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ is a closed curve, not a spiral. The spiral is an artefact of numerical calculus. If you expect a spiral trajectory, the equations $(1)$ , $(2)$ are not a correct model. Rely more on analytic solving than on numerical solving when they are an high number of iterations which introduces cumulative errors.

Comment: You are right, I agree.. Spiral is the result of numerical error and no spiral exist in real. I was mentioning the effect of cumulative effect of error. What I need is x(t) and y(t) , even an approximate analytical solutions is good. This for research purpose in CFD. (Numerical SImulation was intented to just get me an idea how analytical solution would look like without considering the error, eg. circle change to squaring with increase in radius from center.)

Comment: I added  a few equations to my first answer. Not sure that all is OK. I have not enough time to check. I will be away for some days. I'll look again when be back.

Comment: I had got the same equations before, but did not try the definite integral way as I said earlier was stuck with finding inverse of t(x) containing elliptic integral.

 After numerical integration of x and y as you suggested, it is not clear for me how to proceed further.. for example integration can have only one result, whereas there are multiple t for single x, another one would be, when t is negative for x and positive for y when x>xo and y>yo. Some thing to do with periodicity shifts ? Could you what the final result  for  x(t) and y(t) approching in this method and how to get there?