# Find any set of functions $f(x)$ and $g^{-1}(x)$ such that $f(0)=f(1)=f'(0)=f'(1)=0$ and $\int \frac{dx}{f'[f^{-1}(\frac{c}{f(x)})]}=g(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

Find any set of functions $f(x)$ and $g^{-1}(x)$  such that  $f(0)=f(1)=f'(0)=f'(1)=0$ and $\int \frac{dx}{f'[f^{-1}(\frac{c}{f(x)})]}=g(x)$. This is concerned with defining a solenoid velocity field satisfying some boundary conditions and to explicitly solve for its position in time.

The motivation is the below

In CFD for testing the accuracy of advection algorithm, there are certain bench mark tests. For one of the tests. Analytical velocity field is needed given by ${V}=(u,v)$ that is smooth and satisfies $\nabla .V =0   $ inside a square domain with corners $(0,0) \:, (1,1)$. Now it should also satisfy the boundary condition and both $u$ and $v$  is zero at boundaries which means $u(0,y)=u(1,y)=u(x,0)=u(y,0)=0$ similarly for $v$.  There are few already used functions which satisfy these like

$u(x,y)=-sin(2\pi y)sin^2(\pi x)$

$v(x,y)= sin(2\pi x)sin^2(\pi y)$.

But I have found out a cumulative error effect related to dt (time step of numerical simulation). In order to solve that issue I need to solve for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ directly for given initial condition , which is like locations of one point in the path $(x_0,y_0)$.

Now I attempted to do this for the above functions, but it ended up with a need to find the inverse of elliptic integral of first kind which is the same case with other few functions I tried.

So I tried to come up with the function and I started as follows which satisfies divergence condition for all $f(x)$.

$u(x,y)= -f(x)f'(y)$

$v(x,y)= f(y)f'(x)$

Boundary conditions are easily satisfied when $f(0)=f(1)=f'(0)=f'(1)=0$. Going further, find $u/v = dx/dy$, Integrate which gives you the curve $f(x)f(y)=Constant$. From this $y=f^{-1}(\frac{C}{f(x)})$. Now substituting in equation for $u(x,y)$, we get $\int \frac{dx}{f'[f^{-1}(\frac{c}{f(x)})]}= t$. So x(t) will be given by the inverse. That is what I am looking for.

Comment: Something seems very wrong with your condition $f(x)f(y)=const$ because they are functions of different variables, they can't "cancel out" unless they were both constants, but then the only solution would be the trivial solution $f(x)=0$, which can't satisfy the integral you have. Your problem is overconstrained for one, but there is something theoretically wrong about using the same function twice with different variables that makes this issue unavoidable.

Comment: $\frac{dx}{dy}=-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} \frac{f'(y)}{f(y)}$.


$\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} dx  = - \int \frac{f'(y)}{f(y)} dy $ .


$log(f(x)+log(f(y))= constant$.


$f(x)f(y) =constant$

Comment: This line of equations doesn't make any sense to me. Could you explain the first equality? For example, what is $f$? Why does $dx/dy$ equal that? Are you using some sort of implicit function theorem argument?

Comment: we have $\frac{dx}{dt} = -f(x) f'(y)$ --(1)

 $\frac{dy}{dt} = f(y) f'(x)$ --(2)

Now (1)/(2) gives the first equality

Comment: But why? That's not even the functional form for the solution you gave. Think my friend away from the equations and only about logic. The end result makes no sense, since a nontrivial differentiable function of one variable, times the *same* function of a different variable, cannot cancel out to be a constant.

Comment: My friend, It defines the path. Very simple let us say $f(x) = x$. Then what is $f(x)f(y)= C$? it is a collection of points in $xy$ plane such that $xy=Constant$. So $y = C/x$. It is not cancelling out.

For reference
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3427861/how-to-solve-these-two-first-order-non-linear-coupled-differential-equations-tha

Comment: Ah okay, I understand now. But there is another problem now. If you have that $f(0)=f(1)=0$, then Mean Value Theorem tells us that there is a point where the function has to turn around, so it cannot be invertible over the whole domain. Let's say we try to skirt that issue by asserting that the range of $f$ is such that $C/f$ falls in a range where $f$ is invertible. Such functions are not going to easily analytic, so I suggest relaxing two of the constraints. For example, having $f'(0)=f(1)=0$ should be enough and has the readily invertible solution $f(x) = x^2-1$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101006/discussion-between-appoopanthaadi-and-ninad-munshi).